# how to add font size and font family in tinymce 4.2 editor?

Tags: php, jquery

```
   tinymce.init({
            mode : "specific_textareas",
            editor_deselector : "mceNoEditor",
            editor_selector: 'myTextEditor' ,
            theme: 'modern',
            plugins: [
            'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak',
            'searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen'
          ],
            image_advtab: true, 
            toolbar1: 'undo redo | insert | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image',
            toolbar2: 'print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons | codesample help fontselect fontsizeselect',
            rel_list: [
            {title: 'follow', value: 'follow'},
            {title: 'nofollow', value: 'nofollow'}
            ],
            external_plugins: {"nanospell": mypath}, 
            nanospell_server: "php" // choose "php" "asp" "asp.net" or "java"
            });
```

Answer (score 2):

Isn't [this documentation](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-formatting/) right for you?

```js
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',  // change this value according to your HTML
  toolbar: 'fontselect',
  font_formats: 'Arial=arial,helvetica,sans-serif;Courier New=courier new,courier,monospace;AkrutiKndPadmini=Akpdmi-n',
  fontsize_formats: '8pt 10pt 12pt 14pt 18pt 24pt 36pt'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',
  height: 500,
  plugins: 'code',
  toolbar: 'undo redo | fontsizeselect fontselect',
  content_css: ['//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower'],
  font_formats: 'Arial Black=arial black,avant garde;Indie Flower=indie flower, cursive;Times New Roman=times new roman,times;'
});
```

link
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/przvoq

Comment: Although, must of the time, code is self explanatory, you could add some explanation of how that works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for fontsize_formats

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea',
    toolbar: 'fontsizeselect',
    fontsize_formats: "8px 10px 12px 14px 18px 24px 36px"
});
```